# install something to beaglebone green

Tags: command-line, debian, beagleboard, minicom, beagle

I want to install **minicom** to BeagleBone Green.It has debian version 9.3 Linux beaglebone 4.9.82-ti-r102. But when I do `sudo apt-get install minicom` , I get

```
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

how do I install minicom and
is it possible to install at least something on BeagleBone Green
[image]

reaction to `sudo apt update`
[image]

Comment: The Debian team have shuffled commands `apt-get` and its more capable cousin `apt` around over the last years. Try `sudo apt install minicom` just in case. If that reports the same error, you're not running Debian. Try `cat /etc/issue` to see what is your operating system.

Comment: @Tarmo I tried to do as you said. screenshot attached in question

Comment: That's probably because you need to update the list of available packages before installing them: `sudo apt update`